# Do I ever stand up?

Tags: bit-trip-runner

I've noticed that after holding down kick for a while I stop kicking, does the same happen to ducking, as far as I can tell it doesn't.

Also are there any other reasons not to hold down duck all the time? (apart from sore fingers) Such as it interrupting other moves.

Comment: As far as I could tell, there was no disadvantage to holding down 'slide' all the time.  I didn't beat the game though, as this game got boring very fast -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in this [Rage](http://www.youtube.com/user/RageGamingVideos?feature=watch) Perspective

it doesn't seem to stop. I also tested it myself, you can even hold down while jumping and trampolining.